# How to place an image over iframe using proper css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to place an image(which is a close button) on iframe at the top-right corner, the iframe and image are loaded from js function in angular, I have placed it correctly by some CSS but the issue is when the screen is responsive or on the tab or mobile view it doesn't appear in the correct place

Below is the Html code:

```html
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  ">
  <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      position: absolute;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      top: 40px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -200px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    " src="test.html" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
  </iframe>
  <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 23% !important;
      left: 48% !important;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
      z-index: 99999999;
      margin-left: 192px;"
      id="close-overlay"
    " src="assets/images/pink_hair_sml.png" />
</div>
```

The image should be placed at the marked position even if the screen gets minimized or maximized the image should be placed at the same position.

[image]

here is how it should look

[image]

but when I reduce the screen to 75%

[image]

this is how it looks

I am able to fix it for each screen but still when the screen gets minimized or maximized position is not placed correctly

here is parent of the element

[image]

Comment: If you want to position the image on the right, why are you using the css `left` to position it?

Comment: Is there a reason for the iframe to have position absolute? I ask because ideally you want to position the close icon in relation to it.

Comment: @Tom if i don't add left then the image is placing in the middle, I tried since two days I tried to fix with different CSS nothing is working for responsive

Comment: @vinuta can you not use `right`? In your position I would wrap both the iframe and close icon in a div which is the same size as the iframe and then use `position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;` on the close icon

Comment: @AHaworth iframe needs to be placed in the center so add position to it

Comment: @Tom i cannot add anything on html that's is the main issue I am facing, there is js function which I am calling which loads the iframe I have to fix with css

Comment: @Tom both iframe and close icon wrapped in same div

Comment: I am able to fix it for each screen but still when the screen gets minimized or maximized position is not placed correctly

Comment: How about using flex to position the iframe 'group' in the center? What is the parent element of all of the elements you have shown?

Comment: but iframe is already in center the issue is with closing icon

Comment: Please give us a bit more context. Include the fact that you cannot alter the HTML in your question as that is very relevant and show us what the parent element of the three elements is as that will help with positioning. Your use of absolute units (px) means you will not have a responsive set up so we need to get rid of those and work in the context you have been given.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Sorry, but it really is important that you tell us the context in which you are working. You have said you cannot change the HTML, so I assume that means all the inline styling will have to be overwritten by your own CSS using important, is that correct. Also, we still don't know what the parent of these three elements is so we don't know what you are trying to center the iframe (which seems to be the aim from one of your comments) in relation to.

Comment: yes I can override the CSS using important where using that I positioned the iframe in the center but I am not able to place the close image on top-right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241137/discussion-between-vinuta-and-a-haworth).

Comment: I have added the another image where body is the parent for the div

Comment: margin-left: 0 !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
    height: 490px !important;
    min-height: 0px !important;
Using this external css i have made the iframe to center

Answer (score 1):

If you add a div that wraps the 2, you can position that using flex in relation to your to div like so:

```html
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  ">
  <div style="position: relative; max-width: 50%">
    <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    " src="test.html" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
    </iframe>
    <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
      z-index: 99999999;
      id="close-overlay"
    " src="assets/images/pink_hair_sml.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, positioning the wrapping element itself which means you don't have to add a new div, see below. The disadvantage of this is that there's then space not covered by the div itself and so whatever's underneath then shows through.

```html
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 25%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  ">
    <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      width: 100%;
    " src="test.html" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
    </iframe>
    <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 99999999;
      id="close-overlay"
    " src="assets/images/pink_hair_sml.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: but I cannot include div as I don't have access to HTML

Comment: underneath can be shown as it will be pop uo but still the position of button doesn't seems correct

Comment: oh you have removed the width of div no no it cant be done div much be full width of screen

Comment: What's not correct about the button position? Do you want it ON the corner, rather than inside the iframe? If so you can just do top: 0 and right 0

Comment: left should 0px

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7wsmm?file=src%2Fstyles.css
This can helps you to understand in better way

Comment: In that demo you're also fighting your styles.css file, which is setting other styling and forcing you to use `!important`, which is unnecessary.

Comment: then what is the solution i am not getting the CSS which I have used in style.css keeps the iframe in center but I am not able to place the close image at top-right when I resize the screen

Comment: please help me to solve this i am not getting solution for this

Comment: Unless you position your iframe using absolute values (in px) there is no reliable way to position another sibling element in relation to it so that it is responsive. There is essentially a fundamental issue with your DOM structure in that you have no container for both elements that you can position relative to.

Essentially, you need a wrapping div. It is possible to do using some calc values but it's not best practice or robust to changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241140/discussion-between-vinuta-and-tom).

Comment: $iframe = $("#iframe-overlay")

$image = $("#close-overlay")

$("#close-overlay")

.offset(

{

top: $iframe[0].getBoundingClientRect().top-($image.height()/2),

left: $iframe[0].getBoundingClientRect().width - $image.width()

})


This also dint help me

Answer (score 0):

After all your comments that finally explains that you cannot change the HTML code we start to understand what you need!

You have to override the inline CSS rules with the help of the `!important` operator. The big problem will be on the close image
because it already has some `!important` rules in the inline CSS, which is bad news for us... But you can use JavaScript to correct
the horrible HTML generated.

For the CSS itself, I prefer putting all items in position fixed and use % to position them.

The close image should not be set from the left but from the right. But as said before this will be tricky because the inline CSS already has some `!important` rules. But at least we can remove the float and left margin. Finally, after overriding during the battle, the simpliest was just to remove the inline style attribute with JS.
You'll have to find if you can hook somewhere in the JS library. If you cannot then you could run the JS every half a second until it finds the close image, like I did (but it's not a nice solution).

By the way, it would be good to set the image size in the CSS so that it displays at the correct place and size before the image itself is downloaded.

```js
/*
In your case, you'll have to run this once the
iframe is visible. See if you can hook somewhere.
Look at the JS library you are using or if you can
then replace it by one not generating all this
horrible HTML with inline styles.

Here, just for the demo, I finally find a solution
to run it once the document is loaded and also each
time a change is detected, typically the case of the
user clicking on a button or link to display the
iframe overlay. This avoids the solution of a timer
running all the time.
*/

/**
 * Correct the close button of the iframe displayed on overlay.
 */
function correctIframe() {
  let closeImg = document.querySelector('#iframe-overlay ~ img:not(.cleaned)');
  if (closeImg) {
    closeImg.setAttribute('style', '');
    closeImg.setAttribute('class', 'cleaned');
  }
}

// Once the document is loaded we can try to see if there's
// already an iframe overlay to correct it.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', correctIframe);

// Each time the document changes (typically if some JS does
// something such as triggering an Ajax call, loading new HTML,
// or simply displaying the iframe overlay) then we also have
// to correct it.
let domInsertionObserver = new MutationObserver((mutation) => {
  correctIframe();
});
domInsertionObserver.observe(document, { childList: true });
```

```css
#iframe-overlay {
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 10% !important;
  left: 10% !important;
  width: 80% !important;
  height: 80% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

/* An image tag just after the iframe. */
#iframe-overlay ~ img {
  visibility: hidden; /* To avoid seeing it at bad position. */
  z-index: 1001 !important;
  position: fixed !important;
  /*
    We cannot override the left attribute
    because it has !important in the inline
    rule! Bad! We cannot override the transform
    either! Even worth! So JavaScript can only
    save us by deleting the inline style attribute.
  */
  top: 10% !important;
  right: 10% !important;
  /* Adjust to the image size to avoid image
     being resized during the download step. */
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /* Move half of the image size to right and down. */
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) !important;
}

#iframe-overlay ~ img.cleaned {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  ">
  <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      position: absolute;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      top: 40px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -200px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    " src="test.html" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
  </iframe>
  <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 23% !important;
      left: 48% !important;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
      z-index: 99999999;
      margin-left: 192px;"
      id="close-overlay"
    " src="assets/images/pink_hair_sml.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but I can't change to the bootstrap button it is an image I can't add anything on js it's a script I am calling to load iframe with image

Comment: @vinuta: Well, in this case put back the `<img/>` tag. The positionning is the same. So what can you change? is the inline CSS generated or not?  If yes then you can add some CSS rules later with `!important` so that it overrides the inline CSS rules.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d7wsmm?file=src%2Fstyles.css
This can help you to understand in better way

Comment: @vinuta I understood that the JS does this horrible HTML code. So I added some JS to remove the inline CSS rules that we cannot override because of the `!important` used in them.

Comment: $iframe = $("#iframe-overlay") $image = $("#close-overlay") $("#close-overlay") .offset( { top: $iframe[0].getBoundingClientRect().top-($image.height()/2), left: $iframe[0].getBoundingClientRect().width - $image.width() })
How about this one?

Comment: @vinuta I always prefer clean CSS rules which are made for design than doing design with JavaScript. The latter is used for logic and not for rendering. And you'll have some items moving in the page since the JS is run only after. CSS is loaded before painting starts.

Comment: @vinuta I replaced the timer interval by a way to listen to DOM changes, typically your case if the user clicks on a button or link that will display the iframe overlay.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning of the two elements (iframe and img) is pretty straightforward as we know the width of the iframe (it is picking up the default which is set at 300px by browsers see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe ).

However it is rendered somewhat complex by the rather strange set of styles applied inline to the iframe and (worse) to the img where a couple are set !important and therefore not overwritable by our own CSS.

This snippet just gets rid of all the inline styling on those two elements using Javascript and starts again.

It positions each element independently. The iframe is centered and set at 40px from the top of its positioned parent. The img is positioned to just after the right hand edge of the iframe, and then transitioned back by half its width and height to get the overlap.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa" style="
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  ">
    <iframe style="
      display: inherit;
      z-index: 10001;
      position: absolute;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
      top: 40px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -200px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    " src="test.html" id="iframe-overlay" title="iframe">
  </iframe>

    <img style="
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      opacity: 1;
      float: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 23% !important;
      left: 48% !important;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
      z-index: 99999999;
      margin-left: 192px;" id="close-overlay" " src="assets/images/pink_hair_sml.png " />
</div>
<style>
body {
  width: 100vw;
}
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa {
    --iframeW: 300px; /*the defaults set by browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe*/
    --iframeH: 150px;
    }
#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa iframe {
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    top: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: calc(50% - (var(--iframeW) / 2));
    position: absolute;
}

#GlobalPayments-overlay-02d30efa img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: calc(50% + (var(--iframeW) / 2));
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
</style>
<script>
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
const img = document.querySelector('img');
  iframe.style = '';
  img.style = '';
</script>
</body>
```